# Subquery in Rails report generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a report in a Ruby on Rails application and I'm struggling to understand how to use a subquery.

Each 'Survey' has_many 'SurveyResponses' and it is simple enough to retrieve these however I need to group them according to one of the fields, 'jobcode', as I only want to report the information relating to a single jobcode in one line in the report.

However I also need to know the constituent data that makes up the totals for that jobcode.  The reason for this is that I need to calculate data such as medians and standard deviations and so need to know the values that make the total.

My thinking is that I retrieve the distinct jobcodes that were reported on for the survey and then as I loop through these I retrieve the individual responses for each jobcode.

Is this the correct way to do this or should I follow a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a named scope to simplify getting the groups of responses:

```
named_scope :job_group, lambda{|job_code| {:conditions => ["job_code = ?", job_code]}}
```

Put that in your response model, aand use it like this:

```
job.responses.job_group('some job code')
```

and you'll get an array of responses. If you're looking to get the mean of the values of one of the attributes on the responses, you can use map:

```
r = job.responses.job_group('some job code')
r.map(&:total)
=> [1, 5, 3, 8]
```

**Alternatively**, you might find it quicker to write custom SQL in order to get the mean / average / sum of groups of attributes. Going through rails for this sort of work may cause significant lag.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Custom SQL here")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Model.find_by_sql()

For example:

```
class User < Activerecord::Base
  # Your usual AR model
end
```

...

```
def index
  @users = User.find_by_sql "select * from users"
  # etc
end
```